# prevent multiple instances of script in same time

Tags: php

PHP by default does not have multi threading for our apps, but it is possible, that 2 or more users will click same link in same time or, as in my case, multiple API requests are send in same time.

I have script, that creates quite big file when first user does something.

This is what I have in my code:

```php
if (!file_exists($tmp_file)){
   write_file();
}
```

but sometimes multiple instances of that script are launched in same time in 2 separate Apache threads. In that case, it might happen, that file_exists() will return false, but 0.00001s later, when i'm trying to write that file, it already exists, because it was created by simultaneously running script.

Is there any way to detect such situation and prevent it?

I know I can catch an error and simply not display it to the user, but I prefer not to have any error at all.

Comment: If you run into this kind of situation, it is a sign you are already doing the wrong thing.

Comment: The best approach is to create that single file, store user related data in database, then when the user logs on you pull his data from database, use the restored data to populate the page or to do whatever you like. You will never ever need to create same file for each  user. That will become a problem, a serious one sooner or later. So recheck your design and optimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fopen with mode 'x', if the file exists, fopen will return false and a warning.

```
$f = @fopen($tmp_file, 'x');
if($f !== false)
{
    fwrite($f, ....);
    fclose($f);
}
```

If you don't even like the warning, use flock

```
$f = fopen($tmp_file, 'a');
if($f !== false && flock($f, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB) && ftell($f) === 0)
{
   fwrite($f, ....);
   fflush($f);
   flock($f, LOCK_UN);
}
fclose($f);
```